# Not having to type the passphrase in debsign

Tags: linux, debian, digital-signature, deb

I'm building a  debian package ( .deb ) with a continuous integration server ( Hudson ). 
It's work fine for building unsigned package. But i want my hudson-user to be able to sign the package himself, without human intervention.

Basicly, i ask hudson to launch a make file, who use [Debuild](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/fr/man1/debuild.1.html). Debuild itself call [debsign](http://man.he.net/man1/debsign)

debsign need the system to have a pair of key avaiable, and it's the case. But i have to type the associated passphrase each time, and it's break the goal i want to archive (complete auto building of signed package )

My question is : can i avoid to have to type something ? I can change the

Answer (score 0):

If you are building packages on your local machine, use `gpg-agent`. It will remember PGP passphrases for the session. (If using GNOME, the "GNOME Keyring" performs the same function.)

```
eval $(gpg-agent --daemon --sh --use-standard-socket)
```

Comment: If I understand gpg-agent (which I haven't managed to install on my Ubuntu system), then it still requires the user to type the passphrase once. This will still make automatic build impossible - if only because the user will have to enter the passphrase once everytime the system boots.